# C# Script fails at part on script that shouldn't be evaluated anyways

Tags: c#

So admittedly I'm a C# Scrub. I'm writing what should be a very simple script for some Steel Fabrication software (AutoDesk Advance Steel). This is the script

```
= IName.Contains("Bent") ? "TBD" : (IClass.Contains("Nut") ? "": (double)ILength
```

This is being entered in a DataField. In this software, there are many objects like beams, plates, bolts, etc. They all have a property for ILength. My problem comes when an object like a Nut gets passed to it.  Nuts apparently have no length property. So to avoid an error for Nuts I checked for Nuts, if True "" is entered. If False the length property gets entered. However, my script still fails. I was told that C# will evaluate the entire script and every portion has to evaluate properly.

So even though for a Nut, the "False" statement shouldn't matter it apparently does. Is this in fact how C# works or is there a work around?

*Edit*
This is the error

> Control Script failed for control TextBox64,
> Source== IName.Contains("Bent") ? "TBD" : (IClass.Contains("Nut") ? "": (double)ILength

I did notice the original script didn't say NUT. I fixed that but the error is the same.

Comment: Please edit your question and add in the text of the error message.

Comment: There's not enough context here - e.g. no mentioning of `Nuts` in the snippet above - the expression still looks problematic because it can yield a result that's either `string` or `double`, which usually doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional operator only evaluates the expression that actually runs. This is different from, say, the old "immediate if" function (`IIF()`), which as a function needed to evaluated all of the arguments before the function is actually called.

You can see it work in this example:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/WT9Mcf

However, C# is a strongly-typed language.  A missing property is compile-time issue, not a run-time issue that could cause an exception. The code must still compile based on type information known in advance, and if you could reach this code with a known type that does not have the property in question, you will need to change that.